# Rollback Mechanism in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I had an interview and I was asked a question that left me speechless. So I thought maybe I could ask that question here and get the correct answer for it.
The question was as below.

> In Spring, we are using hibernate for database operations. I have a
>   Java Class in which there are multiple objects that needs to be
>   persisted in database(lets say 3 Objects). Now, I want to make sure if
>   the third object fails to be persists, then the first and second
>   Objects should be rolled back. This behavior should be controlled by
>   Spring framework, the question is how can Spring make sure that this
>   behavior is achieved?

Just for my personal understanding, even if i want to make sure that this behavior is achieved in hibernate, how can I achieve that?

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looked into Transaction life cycle and felt it was a bit too hard to digest, so i was expecting some simple definition with few parameters like "Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW". Problem is, I was unable to connect dots to make a clear picture for my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on Spring's `@Transactional` annotation, how it works with AOP proxies, and how a rollback is performed.  To quote the documentation:

> The recommended way to indicate to the Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure that a transaction’s work is to be rolled back is to
>   throw an Exception from code that is currently executing in the
>   context of a transaction. The Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure code will catch any unhandled Exception as it bubbles
>   up the call stack, and make a determination whether to mark the
>   transaction for rollback.
>
> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case
>   of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception
>   is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Errors will also -
>   by default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown
>   from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default
>   configuration.

Reference:

**@Transactional**: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained

**Rolling back**: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

Comment: It would be fantastic if you could give the similar example in Hibernate as well, this will make thing a lot clear. ie, doing same thing in 2 different frameworks.